# Fluent + SQLite : Exception on SetBatchSize()

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent

I'm trying to setup Fluent NHibernate to allow me to do batching.  A NotSupportException is being thrown when I try to session.SetBatchSize(x) that states, "No batch size was defined for the session factory, batching is disabled. Set adonet.batch_size = 1 to enable batching."  However, when I examine the SessionFactory properties there is an entry [adonet.batchsize, 1] .  Is there something I'm blatantly overlooking here?

Factory Creation :

```
factory = Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(
               SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
               .UsingFile(fileName).AdoNetBatchSize(1)
            )
           .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Person>())
           .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
           .BuildConfiguration()
           .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Insert Function :

```
 using(var session = factory.OpenSession())
 using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
 {
       session.SetBatchSize(1); //Exception is being thrown here.

       session.Save(myPerson);  //myPerson uses an assigned Id (not Identity)

       transaction.Commit();
 }
```

The exception is also thrown if I manually set the property itself instead of using the AdoBatchSize method (i.e.  config.Properties["adonet.batch size"] = "1"; ).  Does anything have to be set in the App.Config for batching to working with Fluent NHibernate? 
This Exception seems to be coming from the setter of the BatchSize property of NonBatchingBatcher which throws the argument if you attempt to set it.  If the configuration property for adonet.batch_size is set on the SessionFactory why is it using NonBatchingBatcher versus a SqlClientBatcher?

Thanks, Dubs.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `SetBatchSize` outside the transaction?

Comment: @Rippo : I've tried setting it as soon as the SessionFactory is created.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's only available to Oracle and MS-SQL, since I see Batcher classes for them.  I'm about to trace  through their source code to see why a NonBatchingBatcher is always being generated for me.

Comment: Looked on google and found this, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/hRDr1G78aTs However no one answered so its probably not a good link, however you are not alone.

Comment: I'm beginning to think NHibernate only has batching support for Oracle and MS-SQL.

Comment: yes it is only available for them